# How to enable eslint rule for all *.ts files except for *.stories.ts files?

Tags: angular, eslint, angular-storybook

I have the problem that my eslint rules for *.ts files are also applied on my *.stories.ts storybook files.
How can I tell eslint to ignore such files?

Currently my root eslintrc.json file looks like this

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": ["projects/**/*"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "endOfLine": "auto"
      }
    ]
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      // TODO: find a way to apply rules on all files ending with .ts except for files ending with .stories.ts
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        // https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/tree/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "hv",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "hv",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ],
        // https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules
        "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": "error",
        //  https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/
        "default-case": "error",
        "default-case-last": "error"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        // https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/tree/main/packages/eslint-plugin-template/docs/rules
        "@angular-eslint/template/no-duplicate-attributes": ["error"],
        "@angular-eslint/template/attributes-order": ["error"],
        "@angular-eslint/template/no-call-expression": [
          "error"
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/template/accessibility-elements-content": [
          "error",
          {
            "allowList": [
              "ariaLabel"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/template/accessibility-valid-aria": [
          "error"
        ]
      }
    }
    // {
    //   "files": ["*.stories.@(ts|mjs|cjs)"],
    //   "extends": ["plugin:storybook/recommended"]
    //   // https://github.com/storybookjs/eslint-plugin-storybook/tree/main/docs/rules
    //   // "rules": {}
    // }
  ],
  "extends": ["plugin:storybook/recommended"]
}
```

I also have another eslintrc.json auto generated by storybook in the .storybook folder that looks like that

```
{
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports": ["error", { "disallowTypeAnnotations": false }]
  }
}
```

What do I have to do to make parts of eslint stop linting .stories.ts files?(**I want "plugin:storybook/recommended" to keep doing its lint job, not disable everything**) Especially the "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention" rule is annoying because of "export const Primary" etc. (since it starts with a capital letter)

I already tried

```
files: ["*.ts", "!*.stories.ts"]
```

it didn't work

Comment: Not a clean solution, but at the top of every file you want to disable a rule you could add a comment `/*eslint no-duplicate-attributes: 0*/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a .eslintignore file.
See [The .eslintignore File](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/ignore#the-eslintignore-file)

Comment: But I don't want all eslint rules to ignore *.stories.ts files.. I at least want the "plugin:storybook/recommended" to do its job

Answer (score 0):

Not a clean solution, but at the top of every file you want to disable a rule you could add a comment. As far as I know there is no way to only ignore for certain rules in an `.eslintignore` file.

`/*eslint no-duplicate-attributes: 0*/`